Why does an accelerometer read geavity when at rest?
This may sound like a stupid question but why does an accelerometer read 9.8 (gravity) on the vertical axis when I set it down on a table?
I have just finished AP Physics Mechanics and was under the impression that acceleration is only changing velocity or direction of an object and is caused by a net force, both of which are not true for the accelerometer. It is at rest on a table and the normal force cancels out gravity forces.
But when I think about it in real life, acceleration causes someone to get pushed back in their seat in a car similarly to how gravity pulls things to the ground.
I can't tell where I am going wrong. Thanks for your help!

In simple terms, the high school definition of acceleration is wrong. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576128/

Thank you for the clarification! So would an accelerometer read 0 at apogee if I threw it in the air?

Assuming no air resistance it would actually read 0 from the moment you released it until it hit the ground.
